# Just a enquiry, about Invoke() in Main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, invoke

I have a property that can be modified from a method with `Invoke()`(from thread) and other without `invoke()` in the same class.

what happen if they are called in the same moment?

This is possible? Since can affect the condition in some method.

For example:

```
public class Test{
    public bool testBool { get; set; }

    public void MethodWIthInvoke(){
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            if (testBool)
            {
                testBool = false;
            }
        }));
    }

    public void Method(){
        if (testBool)
        {
            testBool = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It'll be fine as long as `Method()` is only called from the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, `Method()` is only called from the UI thread, What would happen if they run at the same time?

Comment: @Cristian18 They can't, if they're both being run from the same thread.  It'll be doing one or the other.

Comment: @Servy good, thanks you!

Comment: The Test class does not have an Invoke() method so the snippet makes little sense.  If this is actually a Control.Invoke or Dispatcher.Invoke call then it doesn't matter that you make the call from the UI thread.  It can see you doing that and will dispatch the call directly without using the thread interop plumbing.  Just -5 elegance points.  Not using the Invoke() return value means that you could have used BeginInvoke() instead, -10 for that one :)

Comment: @HansPassant This code is only an example, `MethodWIthInvoke()` will supposedly is called from other thread.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why do you need to make the code this way, anyway, since both of the methods will be called from the same thread then it will be fine. I want to suggest another way to write your code as follows:

```
public class Test{
public bool testBool { get; set; }

 public void Method()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                if (testBool)
                {
                    testBool = false;
                }
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            if (testBool)
            {
                testBool = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```